# How to get a Task's “Unique ID” from a Project Web App via REST?

Tags: rest, project-server, ms-project

I'm brand new to MS Project and Project Server / Project Web Apps.

In MS Project Pro, there is a column called "Unique ID" that seems to function like SharePoint's built-in list item "ID" field - an auto-incrementing integer (1 based).

How can I find a task's "Unique ID" from a project that has been saved and published to a Project Web App through Project Server's REST API?

The only "ID" on a Task object retrieved through

```
https://servername/pwa/_api/projectserver/projects('project-id')/tasks('task-id')
```

is a GUID, there doesn't seem to be any property associated with an integer ID.

I found this other [question and answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/689d86cd-2ac0-4bac-9d0c-d77d944a538c/task-level-unique-id-field?forum=projectserver2010general) over on the MSDN help site. It is about Project Server 2010, and about how to show the "Unique ID" field in a report. But the answer says (emphasis mine):

> There are three ID fields in the MSP_EpmTask_UserView; TaskUID,
>   TaskIndex and TaskClientUniqueId. TaskUID is a GUID, TaskIndex
>   corresponds to the Task positional ID and **TaskClientUniqueId
>   corresponds to the Unique Id field in Project Professional.**

So it appears that this information *is* stored somewhere within Project Server, but... how do I get it through REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is that the Unique ID property isn't available on tasks retrieved through the Project *Server* endpoint, but it is available on tasks retrieved through the Project *Data* endpoint. (Yes, in MS Project Server there are **two** REST web services.) A request to

```
https://servername/pwa/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'project-id')/Tasks(guid'task-id')
```

returns an object that has the `TaskClientUniqueId` property available.